# NullPointerException Libgdx

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, tiled

I've seen questions similar to this, but none that would match what I'm experiencing with my Libgdx project (desktop only). I've made a .tmx map using Tiled and copied it to the assets folder, which has two subpackages: gameScreens (with the maps) and tiles. If I open the .tmx map from Eclipse using Tiled it works just fine. Here's the .tmx:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="8" height="8" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="default" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
  <tile id="0">
   <image width="32" height="32" source="../tiles/rock.png"/>
  </tile>
  <tile id="1">
   <image width="32" height="32" source="../tiles/tile_default_1.jpg"/>
  </tile>
  <tile id="2">
   <image width="32" height="32" source="../tiles/tile_default_2.jpg"/>
  </tile>
  <tile id="3">
   <image width="32" height="32" source="../tiles/wall.png"/>
  </tile>
 </tileset>
 <layer name="Camada de Tiles 1" width="8" height="8">
  <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   eJxjYWBgYCGAmXFgZHlGJHFGLPKU8okxH5f78GEAbrAA2Q==
  </data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

I created an abstract class GameState:

```
package com.mygdx.cavedive.game.GameStates;

//imports

public abstract class GameState {

    private static TmxMapLoader mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
    protected static OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer otmr;
    protected static OrthographicCamera cam;

    protected OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer getRenderer() {

        return otmr;

    }

    protected TmxMapLoader getMapLoader() {

        return mapLoader;

    }

    protected void disposeRenderer() {

        otmr.dispose();

    }

}
```

and a class that extends it:

```
package com.mygdx.cavedive.game.GameStates;

//imports

public class Level_1 extends GameState implements Screen {

    private TiledMap map;

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        //Clear the screen
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        otmr.setView(cam);

        //Render the screen
        otmr.render();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

        cam.viewportWidth = width;
        cam.viewportHeight = height;
        cam.update();

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

        map = getMapLoader().load("gameScreens/level1.tmx");
        otmr = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1f / 32f);
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

        dispose();

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

        disposeRenderer();
        map.dispose();

    }

}
```

Now here's what I get:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.loadTilesets(TmxMapLoader.java:246)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:118)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:104)
    at com.mygdx.cavedive.game.GameStates.Level_1.show(Level_1.java:40)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
    at com.mygdx.cavedive.game.App.GameCore.create(GameCore.java:28)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

It has something to do with the tilesets, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: I just discovered that this problem occurs because I loaded separate images to my tileset. Joining them all together in a single .png, however, made it run properly. I still do not know why it works that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "image collection" tileset where each tile refers to its own image was a new feature in Tiled 0.10. Most likely the version of libgdx you're using does not support these kind of tilesets yet.

According to [this issue on github](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2599), libgdx nightlies do support this feature.